# Automating adding sites to IIS7

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, automation, rake

I'm building some scripts for automatically setting up a developer's machine so everyone has an identical setup & configuration.

One thing in particular I want to automate is the configuration in IIS7. We have a bunch of web apps which need to be hosted locally and would ideally like them all set up automatically. Does anyone know of a sensible way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a little bit of [Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/carlosag/microsoft-web-administration-in-iis-7) + a bit of LINQPad and you're laughing.

Answer (score 0):

its fairly easy with the [powershell snap in](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/447/managing-iis-with-the-iis-70-powershell-snap-in/)

**Edit:** The MSDN docs are pretty whack as usual, but if you rummage about enough you can eventually find all the commands available to you